# Aiming towards thumbstick XNA

Tags: c#, xna, angle, xbox360

currently having some fun in XNA programming a topdown shooter towards the XBox-controller but I'm having some issues right now.

So I move my character with the left thumbstick and aim with my right, so essentially I can move in any direction and still shoot in 360 angle.  What I have right now works, but it's very sensitive and "tacky", it likes to stick a bit extra on all the 90 angles before it moves on to the next angle if I'm moving the thumbstick in a perfect outer circle.

So this is what I have right now:

```
direction.X = gpState_new.ThumbSticks.Right.X;
direction.Y = gpState_new.ThumbSticks.Right.Y;
rotation = Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X);
```

And then when I draw the player I use rotation as the angle of which I'm drawing it.
Do you got any tips on how to do this better ?

Fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is because of the "deadzone" on the stick.  The basic fix is probably something like is to use GamePadDeadZone.Circular.  Perhaps before your code, something like

```
GamePadState gpSTate_new = GamePad.GetState(playerIndex, GamePadDeadZone.Circular);
```

A very similar [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35992/xbox-thumbstick-used-to-rotate-sprite-basic-formula-makes-it-stick-or-feel-s) was asked on GameDev (and you can see a more detailed answer there), which you might have better luck on with this kinds of questions in the future.

Comment: This helped some but it still sticks to the 90 angles. Thanks for the answer tho!